# Semantic tree for propositional logic problem

Tags: logic

I've sample sentences like this :

alice will graduate from school if she is diligent in studying and reading various literatures.
She will not graduate school, if she does not pass the exam. If she reads
various literature, she will graduate school. She studies hard. Therefore,
she graduated school.

then i put into some periodic variables , like this :

```
A = alice will graduate from school
B = alice study diligently
C = alice reading various literature
D = alice passed the test
```

and change to logical expression

```
   premise 1 = (A ^ C) -> B
   premise 2 = ~D -> ~A
   premise 3 = C -> A
   premise 4 = B
   premise 5 = ~A
```

and then, I create tree to check valid or not based on this rule : [semantic rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGQf4.png)

and here is my tree that  try

```
          D
          | (Rule 8 on premise 2)
         ~A
        /   \
       /     \
      ~C     A (Rule 3 on premise 3)
      / \    -------
     /   \    closed
    /     \  
   /       \  
 ~(A^C)     B  (Rule 3 on premise 1)
    /       \
   /         \
  ~A         ~B  (Rule 6 on premise 1)
-------   --------
closed     closed
```

and i confused here how about premise 4 and premise 5 that they're only just has 1 periodic variable and any mistake with my step there ?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of mistakes:

First: Your first premise translates as $(B \land C) \to A$ ... at least as it is stated by you. I am wondering though: should it be $(B \land C) \to D$? For otherwise, this argument never does anything of interest with $D$ ... so, can you please check if you have written down the right English sentence here?

Second: for the second premise, you should get *two* branches: one with $\neg \neg D$, and the other with $\neg A$

Third: the $\neg (A \land C)$ should be split into *two* branches: one with $\neg A$ and one with $\neg C$

Fourth: I have no idea how you get to $\neg B$ ... and how is it that you apply a rule to premise 1 again? You have already decomposed premise 1, and once you have decomposed a statement, you can check it off.

I think that your $\neg B$ was supposed to be a $\neg C$ that came from decomposing the $\neg (A \land C)$ ... so then the rule is not applied to premise 1 ... but more importantly: you put the $\neg C$ in the other branch you already had open. That's a big mistake: you should always branch *within* the branch where the statement is found, and *not* put any of the decomposed statements in any other branches. So, it should look like:

```
      ~C
     / \
    /   \
 ~(A^C)  B
  / \
 /   \
~A    ~C
```

Comment: oops , ya sorry ~B it should be ~C branch of ¬(∧)

Comment: i've been fix my premises like what u said : https://postimg.cc/w1T5z13m, from here is it ok or any mistakes ?

Comment: Your second premise now has $\neg \neg D \to A$?  And did you check the english sentence for the first premise?  IT's aeird how so many premise refer to $A$, but only  one premise refers to $D$ ...

Comment: ya, i was check it ... and ya, it's ~~ D -> A ...

Comment: and i am consufed how about premises with 1 variable there ? there no rule for 1 variable ..

Comment: wait, why ~D change to ~~ D ? i think it should ~D

Comment: @RobyFirnandoYusuf The premise should be $\neg D \to A$ .... but when you use rule 8, note that you need to negate the antecedent, so in the left branch you get $\neg \neg D$, and in the right branch you get $A$. Also, there is indeed no decomposition rule for an atomic variable like $B$ alone.... and that is because there is nothing to be decomposed!  OK, so how then do you use something like $B$? Well, you can use $B$ to close any branch it is in when that branch also contains $\neg B$